# Changing host in a role

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I was assigned to create playbook that will be used by all teams within our department.
Under this circumstances it has to be flexible. It should allow to choose technologies (depending on project/release) and to control execution servers. Playbook should take properties file like the sample below:

```
installationSequenceSet:
  Oracle:
    install: True
    build: true
    inventoryHost: "localhost"
...
  Apps:
    install: False
    build: True
    inventoryHost: "OTHER_HOST"
```

in installation role I would like to execute necessary roles in following way:

```
- name: "Install components with specified sequence"
  include_role:
    name: "main.install{{ v_component.key }}"
  with_items: "{{ specifiedInstallationSequence }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: v_component
  when: v_component in installationComponents
```

where main.install{{ v_component.key }} could be evaluated to main.installOracle.
In main.installOracle and other roles I would like to set hosts to {{ specifiedInstallationSequence.installationSequenceSet['Oracle'].inventoryHost }} so that all tasks and underlying roles would be executed on that hosts.

I was trying to begin main.install{{technology}} with

```
---
- hosts: "{{ specifiedInstallationSequence.installationSequenceSet['Oracle'].inventoryHost }}"
  tasks:
```

but I'm getting errors

```
ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>

The error appears to be in '/path/roles/install/main.installOracle/tasks/main.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- hosts: [OCL_GATEWAY]
  ^ here
```

(OCL_GATEWAY is hardcoded host, for testing purposes, available in inventory)

I tried many ways and I'm stuck, help/sugesstions will be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the full error message in your question?

Comment: Seems to me that you're going about it all wrong.  Each department should have its own inventory and property files (which should be in `group_vars` and `host_vars` folders in the inventory).